# How To Modify Alfresco Share Login Page?

Tags: html, css, authentication, share, alfresco

I've been messing around with this for some time, but I can't seem to find the exact file I need to change in order to get the Share login page to look how I want.

Basically I wanted to do was:

- Change the logo that appears (done..I modified the `C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\themes\default\login.css`)

  Get rid of the copyright text (done..I modified the `C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\themes\default\login.css`)

  Center the logo, the input boxes and the "login" button

  Remove the "Alfresco >> Login" title at the top left of the page.

I've been looking around on Google, and I was surprised to not see more people having tried to do this. Does anyone have any experience with this or know what I might need to do to get the Share login page to look exactly how I want it?

Btw, here is my `login.css` page now if it matters...

```
.login-panel
{
   text-align: left;
}

.login-panel input
{
   border: 1px solid #C5D6E2;
   padding: 2px;
   font-weight: normal;
   font:99% arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
}

.alfresco-share .sticky-wrapper
{
   background-color: #B4B4B4;
}

.yui-panel-container.shadow .underlay
{
   display: none;
}

.yui-skin-sam .yui-panel
{
   border-style: none;
}

.login-panel
{
   width: 502px;
   height: 289px;
   background: transparent url("./images/loginbg.png") no-repeat;
   padding-left: 28px;
   font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #515354;
   visibility: hidden;
}

.login-button
{
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.login-copyright
{
   font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
   font-size: 0px;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: #ffffff;
}

.login-logo
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 16px;
   height: 64px;
   width: 450px;
   background: transparent url("./images/newLogo.gif") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the copyright notice?

Comment: It's still not clear what you want and what the problems are at the moment.

Comment: @WillAbson Just to enhance the look and feel of the page, make it as simple as possible.

Comment: @Tahir Malik Well basically I just want to figure out how to do the last two bullet points listed above. The way I was able to modify the first two bullet points, I have not been able to do anything on the `login.css` in order to change either the title of the page or the center alignment. And I saw in the `C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/jsp` folder there is a `login.jsp` page there and was wondering if there was something similar to modify for share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the `slingshot-login.ftl` which is in `alfresco/templates/org/alfresco/global/slingshot-login.ftl`

Just copy that file to the web-extension and change the things you like :)

Comment: I see a lot of things I was talking about on that page, but looking through that page, the included `alfresco-template.ftl`, and additionally included `alfresco-common.ftl` I still don't see anything related to the "Alfresco >> Login" title.  that appears at the top left of the page.

Comment: After a lot of searching again, I was able to figure it out. You were on the right track in pointing to the slingshot file, but to change the title you ultimately have to change the `C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\messages\slingshot.properties` file and in my case, the `C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\messages\slingshot_en.properties `. In there I just changed `page.title=Alfresco &raquo; {0}` to `page.title=newTitle &raquo`. Easy enough. Thanks again for the help though. :)

Comment: No problem, I thought that you were already familiar with the properties files. Still I'd recommend not to change core filed and rather change them in the web-extension folder.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are interested in a extensions-based approach. Extension modules is a new feature available since 4.0 version.

You can do a lot of customization by taking advantage of this feature, but in order to do what you need to do, you can simply provide an extra CSS file which overrides `login.css` (regardless the theme applied) on every request. If you are interested, [this post](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/ddraper/2012/01/04/extensibilty-updates-roundup/) will be useful to you.

Hope it helps.